# Evict items from the EF DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, dependency-injection, ef-code-first, dbcontext

In my project I am using EF Code First 4.3. Sometimes, I have to call a stored procedure that does a heavy operation, and that operation modifies some entities, but because the EF DbContext identity map I cannot see the changes unless I create a new DbContext.

Is there a way to to that without recreate the DbContext? I get it by dependency injection, and I would prefer not to break that, since it is quite handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can clear the cache, but you can force the context to reload particular entities.

**To reload a single entity:**

```
context.Entry(entity).Reload();
```

**To reload all entities of a particular type:**

```
foreach (DbEntityEntry<T> entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>())
{
   entry.Reload();
}
```

**To reload all entities:**

```
foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
   entry.Reload();
}
```